# How can I get a specific value from an array for my object?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have an array like this:

```
var me = ["Ulvi Rustamli",25];
```

Then I declare a function:

```
var myName = function (string) {
var cutIt = myArray.join(" ").split(" ");
return cutIt;
}
```

Now I need to get the "age" from this function to put into my object.. How can I do it ?

```
var myObj = {
myAge = ????
myFullName = ???
};
```

---

For over an hour, I have been trying to solve it, but couldn't properly do it. Would appreciate any guide :)

Comment: Have you done something like use `console.dir(myName)` to see what the result of that function is?

Comment: Couldn't you have just done this? `var myFullName = me[0]; var myAge = me[1]`???

Comment: No, I have to pass the value from my function to the object :) That's what Im asking. And If you noticed, I first transformed my array into a string, then made them look ["Ulvi","Rustamli",25] by using split(" "); method. So, I have to figure out how can I pass my name and surname into one property :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not return the object from within the function?

```
function foo(arr) {
  var aux = arr[0].split(' ');

  return {
    myAge: arr[1],
    myFullName: arr[0],
    myName: aux[0]
  }
}

var me = ["Ulvi Rustamli",25];
var myObj = foo(me);
```

Comment: How would you call myFullName inside an object literal ?

Comment: Can you also please explain me what did you mean by var myObj = foo(me); ? Did you reference to the array ? I'm trying to understand everything behind each single line of code

Comment: I'm passing a reference of the array to the function "foo". This function "foo" breaks the array down and creates an object with the needed fields. This object is returned and assigned to the myObj variable.

Comment: Thanks! I understand it now.

Comment: Great, please don't forget to accept the answer if useful

Comment: One more question, how can I call function inside my object so I can get the myName value with it. Is this possible ?

Comment: Just add `getMyName:function() {return this.myName;}` in the object literal. Then get the name as `var myName = obj.getMyName()`. But there are better ways to achieve it, see Javascript Prototypes

Answer (score 0):

The age will always be the last element in the array.

```
var meArr = myName(me);
var age = meArr[meArr.length-1]; // Get last element
var myFullName = meArr.slice(0, -1).join(" "); // Join all but the last element
```